# How to resolve a variable?

Tags: java, variables

I'm making a Nim game, and I am adding a single player mode. For this, I created a method (not sure if that is what you call it), and called it at the end of the user's turn. An error message popped up saying: "variable not resolved." Is it the placement of my code? Please help.

I tried creating the variable again, and just calling the variable.

Here is the code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random; 
public class nim {

    public static void computerMove() {
        Random randA = new Random();
        int pcPilePick = randA.nextInt(10);

        Object amtInPile;
        if (pcPilePick == 1) {
            amtInPile = stones1;
        }
        if (pcPilePick == 2) {
            amtInPile = stones2;
        }
        if (pcPilePick == 3) {
            amtInPile = stones3;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome!");
        System.out.println("This is the game of Nim.");
        System.out.println("[1]Single player or [2]multiplayer?");
        String choice = input.nextLine();
        int gameMode = Integer.parseInt(choice);

        int stones1 = 9;// These variables will be used
        int stones2 = 9;// in order to subtract a number
        int stones3 = 9;// of stones from the pile.

        int tStones = stones1 + stones2 + stones3;

        while (tStones > 0) {
            System.out.println("[1] Pile 1:   " + stones1);  //This stack will display 
            System.out.println("[2] Pile 2:   " + stones2);  //the stone count for 
            System.out.println("[3] Pile 3:   " + stones3);  //each pile after the first move. 

            System.out.println("From which pile would you like to take?");
            String aMove = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("How many stones would you like to take?");
            String bMove = input.nextLine();
            int pilePick = Integer.parseInt(aMove);
            int amtInPile = 0;
            if (pilePick == 1) {
                amtInPile = stones1;
            }
            if (pilePick == 2) {
                amtInPile = stones2;
            }
            if (pilePick == 3) {
                amtInPile = stones3;
            }

            int stonePick = Integer.parseInt(bMove);

            /*All the while loops after this comment are
             *used in order to prevent stupid answers.
             */
        //legal move
            //illegal move
            if (pilePick > 3 || stonePick > amtInPile) {
                System.out.println("But nothing happened!");

                System.out.println("That move is invalid");
                pilePick = 0;
                stonePick = 0; // ensure that for an illegal move, nothing will change. 
            }
            if (pilePick == 1) {            //This stack of code will
                stones1 = stones1 - stonePick;
            }
            if (pilePick == 2) {            // subtract stones based on the
                stones2 = stones2 - stonePick;
            }
            if (pilePick == 3) {           // pile input and stone input. 
                stones3 = stones3 - stonePick;
            }
            tStones = stones1 + stones2 + stones3;
            if (stones1 + stones2 + stones3 > 0) {
                System.out.println("Taking " + stonePick + " stones from stack " + pilePick);
            }
            if (gameMode == 1) {
                computerMove();
            }

        }
        System.out.println("You lose!");
    }

}
```

Comment: what's the exact error?

Comment: it appears as if you are trying to refer to variables that are defined only in your `main` method in your `computerMove` method. Make those variables `private static` and put them in your class.

Comment: What's the exact error and *where*'s the exact error?

Comment: Look where your variable is referenced.  Scan backwards through the method, looking for where the variable is declared.  But (important), as you scan, skip over any block of code completely enclosed in `{...}`. Do you find the variable declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `stones1`, `stones2` and `stones3` only have context within the `main` method, they are undefined within the `computerMove` method

You could define them as `static` class variables, but this is start of a slippery slope of bad habits, instead, modify the `computerMove` method to accept the information it needs

```
public static void computerMove(int stone1, int stone2, int stone3) {
    Random randA = new Random();
    int pcPilePick = randA.nextInt(10);

    Object amtInPile;
    if (pcPilePick == 1) {
        amtInPile = stones1;
    }
    if (pcPilePick == 2) {
        amtInPile = stones2;
    }
    if (pcPilePick == 3) {
        amtInPile = stones3;
    }
}
```

Now calling `computeMove` does something, but it has no context beyond the method itself, so you will likely need to return the value

```
public static int computerMove(int stone1, int stone2, int stone3) {
    //...
    return amtInPile;
}
```

Which you can then maintain in the same context from which you called it...

```
int computerPile = 0;
//...
if (gameMode == 1) {
    computerPile = computerMove(stones1, stones2, stones3);
}
```

Take a look at [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

In your if statements from line 8->16 in method `computeMove`, you reference undefined variables `stones1, stones2, stones3`.  You need to declare these variables to reference them, or pass them in as arguments (which is probably what you want).

```
public static void computerMove(int stones1, int stones2, int stones3){
    Random randA = new Random();
    int pcPilePick = randA.nextInt(10);

    Object amtInPile;
    if (pcPilePick==1){
        amtInPile = stones1;
    }
    if (pcPilePick==2){
        amtInPile = stones2;
    }
    if (pcPilePick==3){
        amtInPile = stones3;
    }
}
```

and change the function call on line 87 to:

```
computerMove(stones1, stones2, stones3);
```